# Which case does all of users' inproc session die?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis, webforms, windows-server

I have asp.net web forms application. I deployed program to IIS server and program is working well but all of users' `InProc` session often die at same time. The same time connected users count is about 250. In Application pool I changed only enable 32-bit applications as true other settings are default. I looked application pool occupy max 300000 b memory in task manager. I want to know what case dose all of users session die?. How to solve this problem?

**Update**

I looked event log. I found out app pool was recycle.

> A process serving application pool 'App pool' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service

Comment: What session mode do you use? Edit your question to include such essential information.

Comment: @LexLi I updated my question

Comment: In process mode can easily lead to issues like that, whenever IIS worker process exits (that removes all sessions from the memory). Read Windows event log to see if IIS generated log entries to guide you, and a tool like Debug Diag can usually tell what makes IIS exit, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2014/01/09/debug-diagnostic-2-0-creating-a-rule-in-crash-mode/